# If $H<G$ are finite groups, must there be a way to realize them as permutation groups such that $H$ is not transitive?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $H<G$ be finite groups.  Must there be a positive integer $n$ such that there exists a homomorphism $f:G\to S_n$ with $f(G)$ transitive and $f(H)$ not transitive?

If $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then we can consider $G/H\hookrightarrow S_{\lvert G/H\rvert}$.

Comment: What is the role of "$m$" in your problem statement?

Comment: Hint: Cayley presentation of $G$ (when $n=|G|$)

Comment: @EricTowers Oops, I was originally going to say "and $H$ only acts on the first $m$ elements of $S_n$", but then I wrote it the way that I did; I have now removed $m$ from the post.

Comment: Oh dear, I've just realized that "transitive" was not equivalent to what I wanted to say at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lord Shark the Unknown has already answered the question, but here is another answer:

Let $n = [G:H]$, and define $\phi:G\rightarrow S_n$ as $G$'s left translation action on the left cosets of $H$. The $G$-action is transitive, but the action restricted to $H$ has the coset $H$ as a fixed point.

A generalization encompassing both answers is: let $K$ be any subgroup of $H$; define $n=[G:K]$, and define $\phi:G\rightarrow S_n$ as the left-translation action on the left cosets of $K$. As before, the $G$-action is transitive, but the restriction to $H$ cannot move the coset $K$ to any coset of $K$ lying outside $H$.

The above takes $K=H$, and Lord Shark the Unknown's answer takes $K=\{1\}$.

**Addendum 6/28/18:** Yet another answer. Let $K$ be any proper subgroup of $G$ *containing* $H$. Just as with $K=H$, the $G$-action is transitive while the $H$-action has $K$ as a fixed point.

This prompts me to ask a more comprehensive version of the question. Let $H\subset G$ be a proper subgroup and let $G\rightarrow S_n$ be a transitive action. Under what circumstances is the restriction to $H$ transitive?

Since any transitive action is isomorphic to a translation action on left cosets, there is a subgroup $K$ such that $n=[G:K]$ and we can identify the elements of the set being acted on with left cosets of $K$. Then the action of $H$ is transitive if and only if $H$ meets each of $K$'s cosets. $H$ containing and being contained in $K$ are both ways to guarantee that $H$ fails to meet all of $K$'s left cosets, but they are not the only ways this can happen.

**Addendum 12/10/18:** Keeping notation as in the previous addendum ($K$ is any subgroup of $G$, giving a transitive action by $G$ on the left cosets of $K$; $H$ is a specific subgroup and we wish to know if the restriction of the action to $H$ is also transitive), we know the restriction to $H$ is transitive if $H$ meets every coset of $K$.

This is equivalent to $HK = G$. The above results can be explained as $K\subset H \Rightarrow HK = H <G$, and $H\subset K \Rightarrow HK = K < G$. But anything that guarantees $HK < G$ will also do, e.g. if $|H||K|<|G|$. Thus take $K$ to be any subgroup with order $<$ the index of $H$.

Comment: ...and this also answers the intended version of my question as well!

Answer (score 5):

Let $n=|G|$. Then the regular representation of $G$ is a homomorphism
$f:G\to S_n$ whose image is simply transitive. If $H$ is a proper subgroup
of $G$ then $f(H)$ is a non-transitive subgroup of $S_n$.

Comment: Why do you believe $f(G)$ acts transitively on $f(G)$ but $f(H)$ does not act transitively on $f(H)$?  Alternatively, unless $f$ is surjective, why do you believe your non-transitivity argument for $f(H)$ does not apply mutis mutandis to $f(G)$?

Comment: @EricTowers I can't make much sense of your question! $f(G)$ is a transitive subgroup of $S_n$ by standard properties of the regular representation, and $f(H)$  is intransitive when $H \ne G$. I don't know what you mean by $f(H)$ acting on $f(H)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt : You and OP present the same imprecision.  A group is transitive if its action is transitive.  Action on what?  Unless $f$ is surjective, $f(G)$ does not act transitively on $S_n$ and a proper subgroup of $f(G)$ will not either.  So generically neither is transitive (although this can be forced for small enough $n$).  The only other interpretation, the one begged by the second paragraph of the OP, is $f(G)$  acts on $f(G)$ and $f(H)$ acts on $f(H)$.  Then Jyrki Lahtonen's comment applies, making both transitive.

Comment: @EricTowers I don't think we are communicating very well here. I find the three sentences in the above answer completely clear, unambiguous and correct. I have no idea what you mean by $f(G)$ acting on $S_n$. $f(G)$ is a subgroup of $S_n$, and is transitive with trivial stabilizers. There is no particular need to involve group actions in the above statements at all. You can define what it means for a subgroup of $S_n$ to be transitive without involving group actions.

Comment: @DerekHolt : Transitivity of a group is defined relative to its action on a set.  Which set?

Comment: To my mind (this is just the way I learnt the subject myself a long time ago)  you have it the wrong way round. $S_n$ is by definition the  group of all permutations of a set $X$ of size $n$. A subgroup $H$ of $S_n$ (which is called a permutation group) is transitive if for all $x,y \in X$ there exists $g \in H$ with $x^g=y$ (or $g(x)=y$ if you prefer). An action of a group $G$ on a set $X$ is a homomorphism $\phi:G \to {\rm Sym}(X)$, and the action is transiitve if its image is a transitive subgroup of ${\rm Sym}(X)$.

Comment: And I *believe* I understand it equivalently, using the words: the group is transitive if the $G$-orbit of some element of $\mathrm{Sym}(X)$ is all of $\mathrm{Sym}(X)$.  This is, of course, impossible for $G = \mathrm{Z}/4\mathrm{Z}$ and $m = 5$ (so that $\mathrm{Sym}(X)$ is $S_n$ for $n \geq 6$) since the $G$-orbits are too small.

Comment: @EricTowers Read more carefully what Derek said (and the Lord Shark obviously intended). The set being acted on is $X$, not $Sym(X)$. [The Cayley representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem) sends $G$ to a transitive subgroup of $Sym(G)$ (acting on $G$). The orbits of $H$ are its cosets on $G$. There are many of those, so that action is not transitive. $G$, OTOH, has only a single coset in itself.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : Why do you believe $n$ is as small as $|G|$?

Comment: @EricTowers The way I read the question we are free to choose $n$. I agree with you that the OP should clarify the meaning of the variable $m$.